# Strategy validation searching criteria. FluentValidation .NET Core

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I have a problem with object validation in my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API with FluentValidation. I have criteria objects with many properties, and some rules with a combination of properties to start a search. I want to return the validation result when any of the combinations of properties is valid and then use this rule.

For example `Name.NotEmpty()+Surname.NotEmpty` or `Surname.NotEmpty()+DateOfBirth.LessThan(DateTime.Now)` or `Gender+Nationality`.

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

To implement validation rules like "Name.NotEmpty() + Surname.NotEmpty" or "Surname.NotEmpty() + DateOfBirth.LessThan(DateTime.Now)" or "Gender + Nationality," you can create a custom FluentValidation validator for your criteria object that encapsulates these rules.

Here's an example of how to implement such a validator:

```
public class YourCriteriaObjectValidator : AbstractValidator<YourCriteriaObject>
{
    public YourCriteriaObjectValidator()
    {
        // Rule 1: Name.NotEmpty() + Surname.NotEmpty
        RuleSet("NameSurname", () =>
        {
            RuleFor(criteria => criteria.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Name is required.");
            RuleFor(criteria => criteria.Surname).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Surname is required.");
        });

        // Rule 2: Surname.NotEmpty() + DateOfBirth.LessThan(DateTime.Now)
        RuleSet("SurnameDateOfBirth", () =>
        {
            RuleFor(criteria => criteria.Surname).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Surname is required.");
            RuleFor(criteria => criteria.DateOfBirth)
                .LessThan(DateTime.Now)
                .WithMessage("Date of birth must be less than the current date.");
        });

        // Rule 3: Gender + Nationality
        RuleSet("GenderNationality", () =>
        {
            RuleFor(criteria => criteria.Gender).NotNull().WithMessage("Gender is required.");
            RuleFor(criteria => criteria.Nationality).NotNull().WithMessage("Nationality is required.");
        });
    }
}
```